# League of legends Haram or halal?

Tags: halal-haram, game

League of legends a wide and famous game worldwide,is it halal or haram to play it due to some skins and some items where u can find lee sin "god`s fist" skin and items like tear of goddes or elixir of sorcery, plz answer this question is it ok to play this game and ignore the items and the champions that contains like these things,oh and some other point magic,we know magic is forbidden,what is the right hukum ?

Answer (score 0):

It's not haram. If you're referring to the god references, pop culture does that all that time. It's not literal, it's just all for fun. Extreme awesome power and all that. (Lol I'm sorry I don't play League of Legends often, it's just sitting on my computer...)

Comment: We need an an answer from a scholar.